Do I need a transit visa for France? Nigeria to Spain
I am from Nigeria and I am traveling to Madrid in Spain. I have a Schengen visa for Spain but I am using Air France, which will stop over in CDG for about 2 hours (layover period) before continuing to Madrid. I am only moving from terminal 2E to terminal 2F. Do I require a transit visa for France?
